# Copy Timestamp of xts object to another Matrix in R

Tags: r, time, xts

I am having a bit of difficulty properly extracting timestamps from an `xts` object and putting them into another matrix. Basically, I have an `xts` object with a timestamp column in a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS format, and I want to extract specific times (in order) and put them into a column in another matrix in the exact same format as they are in the `xts` object. For example, let's say I have an `xts` object with a timestamp column given as:

For example, let's say the timestamp column for a matrix called `mat` is given as follows:

```
2000-01-01 09:05:02.333 
2000-01-01 09:06:03.212 
2000-01-01 09:06:04.764 
2000-01-01 09:07:02.211
```

Now let's say I want to take the 2nd and 4th times and put them into another matrix (which I'll call `mat2`), then ideally it should come out like this:

```
         Time             
---------------------------
2000-01-01 09:06:03.212      
2000-01-01 09:07:02.211
```

Now, I know that by using the `index()` function on an `xts` object you can get the timestamp for that object at a particular index value. However, when I try to do this by writing (for example) `mat2[i,"Time"] <- index(mat[i])`, then rather than putting the date/time value from `mat` into `mat2` it instead puts a number into the matrix, not a time, and I'm not sure why that happens. Is there a way to copy the timestamp of an `xts` object and put it into take two different time values from one matrix and put them into two separate columns in a different matrix?

Comment: A matrix can only hold one class of data. The index presumably is a POSIXct time, which when you put it into the other matrix will show as a number representing the seconds since 1970-01-01 midnight.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for that, if that's the case then is there any way to convert the seconds back to the actual time? Or better yet, is there any other way I can directly copy the timestamp from the `xts` object into the matrix?

Comment: I'd make the target matrix an `xts` object as well, so that it has the index capability as well. I presume you can do `index(mat2) <- index(mat1)` if they are the same dimensions.

Comment: I just tried it now, that method doesn't look like it works unfortunately :/

Comment: What about `as.xts(mat2, order.by=index(mat1))` ?

Comment: It would help if you described your larger goal, rather than this issue you've encountered. There's certainly a way to achieve your larger goal, but not if we don't know what that is.

Comment: Thanks, yes that worked nicely :) It was extremely slow though, but I guess it's the best I can hope for haha

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sorry, you posted shortly before I did so I didn't see your reply. What I'm doing is a little bit hard to describe but basically I'm trying to subset my `xts` object based on certain conditions and I want to extract values from the `xts` object (including the timestamp from the `xts` object) and put them into a new matrix

Comment: Why do you want to put them into a matrix?  Why not just use the resulting xts object created by subsetting the original?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich It's mostly because the new matrix I'm creating has very little in common with the original matrix besides the timestamp and maybe one or two columns, so I mostly just wanted to find a proper way to carry it onto a new matrix :) Of course perhaps copying the xts object and then deleting all the columns and then creating new columns would also work, but it's probably not very computationally efficient so I opted not to do that (unless there's a more straightforward way of course)

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding why simple subsetting doesn't work. What's wrong with something like this: `data(sample_matrix); x <- as.xts(sample_matrix); y <- x[1:3,c(2,4)]`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Ordinarily I would be happy with that, but the problem is I'm only interested in the timestamp and not any of the other columns in the original matrix, and since the timestamp isn't a proper column I can't really subset the original matrix (at least as far as I know, I'm very new to R though so I would be surprised if I'm wrong).

Comment: It's really hard to help if you are not specific. "Only interested in the timestamp" doesn't tell me anything about what you want to do with it. 
 When you say, "since the timestamp isn't a proper column I can't really subset the original matrix", I assume the "original matrix" is an xts object.  And I'm not sure how you concluded that you cannot subset xts objects by rows because the timestamp isn't a column... Take a look at the xts and zoo vignettes.  They should help you understand what you can do with the two classes.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Ah sorry, yes I understand what you mean, unfortunately I made the question a bit unclear so I know where the confusion came from. Yes, the original matrix is an `xts` object, and I want copy the timestamp from the original object and put it into a new matrix. The solution given above (i.e. `as.xts(mat2, order.by=index(mat1))`) works for what I want to do (it's actually better than my original idea I think) but my program now seems to run a bit slower, so I was hoping there would be a faster method (I originally tried `matrix2 <- index(xtsmatrix)` but that didn't work properly)